# How to Change Target API Version in Visual Studio 2017 community Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I have installed **VS 2017** Community and created new project and I am getting below error during build
**Error:-**

> project App1 cannot build using Android 6.0 (API Level 23 -
>   Marshmallow) because Android SDK platform for API Level 23 is not
>   installed. Either install it in the Android SDK Manager
>   (Tools->Android->Android SDK Manager...), or change your
>   Xamarin.Android project to target an API version that is installed

Comment: Have you tried opening the project properties? It's on the first tab of it.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your project in the solution explorer and select **Properties**. In the **Android Manifest** tab you can choose the **Target Android Version**.

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot build using Android 6.0 (API Level 23 - Marshmallow) because Android SDK platform for API Level 23 is not installed.

It is caused when your apps are targeting **API Level 23** but you don't have the SDK. (You can always change this setting on your androidmanifest.xml) or right click on your project and select options.

You have to link your Visual Studio with your Android SDK if you already installed the Android SDK.

If you haven't installed any SDK, you can click on Tools -> SDK Manager and install the Android SDK needed for your project.

NB: Don't forget, there are 3 thing you have to consider about the android SDK : Minimum Android SDK, Compile SDK, and Target Android SDK